# Enabling JavaScript in a proxy server script

Tags: php, javascript, proxy

I'm writing a proxy server in PHP. The proxy server works and is able to render HTML, but JavaScript code will not work. Based on research I've done, many other proxy servers also have problems with JavaScript.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
        @set_time_limit(60);
        $fp = fsockopen(".$page.", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
        if (!$fp) {
            echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
        } else {
            $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
            $out .= "Host: ".$hostname."\r\n";
            $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
            fwrite($fp, $out);
            $x=0;
            while (!feof($fp)) {
               echo fgets($fp, 128);   
               fclose($fp);
            }
        }
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is this javascript or anything opened relatively?

Comment: Why would you want a proxy server to render the HTML ? The Proxy is supposed to be a (mostly) passive middle-man in a connection.

Comment: -The problem is only with JavaScript. I don't care about Flash, Java... etc.
-I need a way to display the requested page with JavaScript working, and I'm not sure if there is a better way to do so.